# What types of gear/supplies are "must-haves" for private pilots?

Tags: equipment, student-pilot

Is there certain gear that people consider "must-haves" for a private pilot? Specifically, a new pilot or student pilot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is opinion based.

Comment: @GdD I would say that it could become opinion based but also could go the other way and have some general answers.  It wouldn't be hard to say something like "Access to an airplane" as a must-have for example.

Comment: Taking that logic it becomes too broad @dalearn. Access to an airplane, money, limbs, half a brain are all essentials.

Comment: @GdD Yes, it can *become* too broad but it doesn't have too and easily could turn out to end up with several common-sense answers that are not too broad in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Get a good headset and a decent mobile device that can run a charting app. I use my Moto4 with Avare.

Download The Airplane Flying Handbook -and- The Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge from the FAA site (both free).  Also download the Airman Certification Standards (ACS) for private pilot airplane.

The only books that I usually recommend people actually purchase are the aircraft manual and a written test study guide from ASA, Jeppesen, Gleim, or King.

Answer (score 2):

Flight bag.
Sectional for the area to be flown in.
Headsets usually, to protect hearing, if not to hear ATC better.
POH if not in the plane already.
Kneepad for taking notes, something to write with.
Water.
That's a bare minimum list, for a casual flight in a known area.

Comment: Wouldn't say most of those were must-haves.  I've never owned a flight bag, for instance.  (And got my PPL in the '70s.)  Headphones if you're renting, and the rentals don't come with them; otherwise they're part of the airplane.

Comment: For casual flying in a known area, assuming uncontrolled (class G) airspace, so far I haven't needed to write anything down in-flight. I agree that a way to make notes in-flight can be beneficial if you're flying under, or potentially under, ATC control.

Comment: Sunglasses might also be useful.